# How can I retrieve the revert reason of a failed transaction using web3.js and Metamask?

Tags: javascript, web3js

I'm using web3.eth.Contract.methods.myMethod().send() and metamask to sign the transaction but when the transaction revert I want to display the reason to the user.

Here is the code:

```
let provider = window.ethereum;
const accounts = await provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
const web3_obj = new Web3(provider);
web3_obj.eth.handleRevert = true;
let SMART_CONTRACT = new web3_obj.eth.Contract(
  SMART_CONTRACT_ABI,
  SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS
);
SMART_CONTRACT.methods
    .approveMember(public_key)
    .send({ from: accounts[0]})
    .then(function () {
      successToast("Vote Operation Done Successfully!");
});
```

I tried to enable handleRevert option to get the revert reason but when I did that Metamask keeps sending requests to the blockchain and repeated the same error on the browser console.

[Browser console error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi397.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.